# Namespace Error on django-social-auth

Tags: django

I've added django-social-auth in my django project from the instructions on this page https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth but when I accesed /login/google/ I encountered an error:
 NoReverseMatch at /login/google/
'namespace' is not a registered namespace.

What does it means?

Comment: show us a bit of your code... the URL conf? search for your use of the word 'namespace'...

Answer (score 8):

My guess is that you copy-pasted sample code using "namespace" and didn't replace it by any namespace declared in your app.

If you are not familiar with namespaces, I'd recommend for a first trial to try and make it work without using them.

Comment: Carles your guess is right, I did copy pasted. After reading your comment I realized that the namespace must be substituted with 'social'.  SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'social:complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'social:association_complete'

Comment: @Ronz: exactly, if you use the url conf as in the example where they declare a namespace of "social"...

Comment: I don't have any other SOCIAl_AUTH* key in my settings and I have `url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social'))` in my patterns but doing `{% url 'social:begin' 'google' %}{% if request.GET.next %}` gives me OP's error... what gives?

Comment: @tutuca can you post that as a separate question? You will be able to add more context